# Connecting server-side sessions in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, session

Is it possible to have a "global" server-side session in Java Spring where the client can close out of the window, reopen it, and access that same server-side session? The data would be too large to store client-side and I'm trying to avoid database tables.

Comment: What do you mean "the window"? What you described is standard behavior for cookie-based sessions.

Comment: I mean the browser. Without using clientside cookies. I'm a little new to this, but how is that standard? I thought serverside sessions typically are only alive for as long as the client maintains the connection. Wouldn't closing the browser sever that connection

Comment: First, that applies to the browser as a whole (which is shared through multiple windows and might not get immediately cleared on exit), and second, it depends entirely on how the cookie is specified. I don't recall offhand the out-of-the-box setup for that, but with Spring Session, you can use `DefaultCookieSerialier#setCookieMaxAge` to tell the browser to keep it.

Comment: From my understanding of your comment, you're saying that I could keep a clientside cookie alive (I think?) I know that, but I wouldn't be using browser cookies except to store usernames. The actual data I would hope to recover would be saved in server-side sessions (not the database).